# Phpunit password comparison

Tags: database, testing, passwords, comparison, phpunit

I would like to test a login function that one of the developers produced. What I would like to do is have test-users be created in my setUp and then I would like to use these users to test the login function. I would like to see that it returns the correct boolean when username and password are equal to the ones stored in our database. My problem is that when I am inserting my users at the moment I am giving the passwords in plain-text hence they are being stored in the database in plain-text, however there is an issue here. The login function hashes the password as you are trying to log in as the passwords in the database are hashed when registration is done. So basically the plain-text password I just inserted will never be matched since the login function hashes the password in an attempt to find a match. So what I would need to do is hash the test-user's password as I insert it. How would I go about doing this? This is what my code looks like at the moment:

```
<?php

include 'functions.php';


class Test extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {


protected function setUp(){

global $mysqli;
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'xxx', 'xxxxx', 'xxxxx');


$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO members (id, username, pnumber, password) VALUES  ('200',        'testbrute', '920314', 'xxxxx')");


}


public function testLogin(){

global $mysqli;

    $correctPass = Login('920314','xxxxxx', $mysqli);
    $this->assertTrue($correctPass);


    $wrongPass = Login('920314','xxxxxxxxx', $mysqli);
    $this->assertFalse($wrongPass);


$NoUserExists = Login("980611-5298","--..--..--", $mysqli);
$this->assertFalse($NoUserExists);

}


protected function tearDown(){
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'xxx', 'xxxxx', 'xxxxx'); 



$mysqli->query("DELETE FROM members WHERE id IN (200)");


}

}
?>
```

This is what the login function looks like:

```
function login($pnumber, $password, $mysqli) {
 // Using prepared Statements means that SQL injection is not possible. 
 if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, username, password, salt FROM members WHERE     pnumber = ? LIMIT 1")) { 
  $stmt->bind_param('s', $pnumber); // Bind "$pnumber" to parameter.
  $stmt->execute(); // Execute the prepared query.
  $stmt->store_result();
  $stmt->bind_result($user_id, $username, $db_password, $salt); // get variables from  result.
  $stmt->fetch();
  $password = hash('sha512', $password.$salt); // hash the password with the unique salt.

  if($stmt->num_rows == 1) { // If the user exists
     // We check if the account is locked from too many login attempts
     if(checkbrute($user_id, $mysqli) == true) { 
        // Account is locked
        // Send an email to user saying their account is locked
        return "account locked";
     } else {
     if($db_password == $password) { // Check if the password in the database matches the password the user submitted. 
        // Password is correct!

           $ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; // Get the IP address of the user. 
           $user_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; // Get the user-agent string of the user.

           $user_id = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "", $user_id); // XSS protection as we     might print this value
           $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id; 
           $username = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+/", "", $username); // XSS     protection as we might print this value
           $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
           $_SESSION['login_string'] = hash('sha512',        $password.$ip_address.$user_browser);
           // Login successful.
           return "login successful";    
     } else {
        // Password is not correct
        // We record this attempt in the database
        $now = time();
        $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO login_attempts (user_id, time) VALUES ('$user_id',  '$now')");
        return 'pass incorrect';
     }
  }
  } else {
     // No user exists. 
     return 'no exist';
      }
   }
}
```

I am new to phpunit and testing in general so please be overly-descriptive.

Comment: Why don't you hash passwords before insert with the same algorithm as you use in code?

Comment: The thing is we have a complicated registration file that handles initial hashing and salting, do you mean I can just insert a random salt in my insert statement here and then use the hash algorithm?

Comment: You should just prepare data the same way as it is in registration code I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget trying to test against the actual database.  As a general rule, you don't want to have your tests dependent on external services if you can help it.

You can inject a mock `mysqli` object and specify it's behavior.  Then you don't have to worry about any values being added to the database or are dependent on having the database even exist.

So in your test rather than declaring a `global $mysqli` do:

```
$mockMysqli = $this->getMockBuilder('mysqli')
                   ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                   ->setMethods(array('prepare'))
                   ->getMock();

$mockMysqli->expects($this->once())
           ->method('prepare')
           ->will($this->returnValue($mockStmt) //Have to also create a mock mysqli_stmt object
```

Based on how your function is, you will end up with a few mock objects returning other mock objects which is a code smell that you function is doing too much.  Because of this, you would be better off breaking it up into smaller pieces that can then be mocked and tested separately.  I find that generally speaking if the function is hard to test, that it is not a good design and should be refactored.  Most good designs end up being easy to test with one or two mock objects.